# Split items separated by commas (,) in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, split

My Javascript var contains a 2D array.
If I pop an alert on the the var i get the JSON serialized result, something like:

```
ID0, DESCRIPTION
```

I'd like to get each items separated by the , in the value option of the dropdownlist and the other item in the description.

Here's my Javascript code, it would work if split was working correctly but this pops an error because the var doesn't contain a pure string type.

```
$.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            url: "Projet.aspx/GetDir",
            data: "{VP:'" + dd_effort_vp + "',DP:'" + dd_effort_dp + "',Direction:'" + dd_effort_d + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(response) {
                   var cars = response.d;
                    $.each(cars, function(index, value) {
                    $('#<%= dd_effort_directionp.clientid()%>').append(
                 $('<option</option>').val(value[value.split(",",0)]).html(value.split(",",1))





                }
            }
        });
```

I know split doesn't work that way here because of the return value is not a string but you get the result i'd like to achieve, get the first value before the comma has the VALUE of the Dropdownlist and the item after the comma as the HTML text.

Thanks ALOT!

Comment: So is your problem solved now? If yes, please accpet the answer which helped you most. Or if not, could you provide us with a little more data?

Answer (score 6):

How about `value.split(",")[0]` instead of `value.split(",",0)`?

Comment: Ah sorry my bad, I might not have fully understood what you were asking - where does value actually come from? and You say it contains an array already? then value[0] / value[1] should work?

Comment: the split doesn't work at all. Says object doesn't suppor this method (split)

Comment: Would help to see what exactly is in the value variable. Is it a JSON encoded array? Then I guess JSON.parse(value)[0] would do the trick.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried `value.toString().split(",")`?